# crypt() breaks when migrating from PHP 5.2 to 5.4

Tags: php, crypt

I have a system running on PHP version 5.2.10 Unfortunately the original programmer misunderstood how crypt() was implemented.

```
$crypt = crypt(trim($cuPassword), CRYPT_BLOWFISH); 
// The programmer thought this is how you configure a blowfish cipher
```

nb CRYPT_BLOWFISH has a value of zero on this machine.

This works in as much as it produces a random looking password hash  eg 0$oZ534I2VvSw

Today, I migrated the software to PHP 5.4.9 and discovered that $crypt becomes *0 , ie an error due to the invalid salt.

My problem is that I have a table of login passwords that I can no longer validate. My question: Is there going to be a way I can recreate the original cipher that ran under version 5.2? What hash was implemented when you passed "0" as a salt?

Comment: Further analysis: It appears to default to a CRYPT_STD_DES using "0$" as the salt. The later version of PHP rejects this as an invalid salt.

Comment: Are you using the Suhosin patch? Because this behavior does not follow stock PHP behavior from what I can reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried all valid two digit combinations (CRYPT_STD_DES) and I found that "0q" is equivalent (nearly).

**PHP 5.2.10**
    crypt(trim($cuPassword), CRYPT_BLOWFISH);

Result = 0$txv6CWBxJ9Y

**PHP 5.4.9**
    crypt(trim($cuPassword), '0q');

Result = 0qtxv6CWBxJ9Y

All I need to do is adjust the second character and I can match passwords again.

Comment: I just tried that independently, and came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your description doesn't really add up. In PHP 5.4.9, I tested this:

```
var_dump(crypt('hello', 0));
```

Output:

```
0$ny0efnQXFkE
```

Now in PHP 5.5, you'll get `*0` when calling `crypt('hello', 0)`. But that's okay! Because this is still true in PHP 5.5: this `crypt('hello', '0$ny0efnQXFkE') == '0$ny0efnQXFkE'`.

All you need to do is change how you generate your hash for new passwords. Validating existing passwords will continue to work.

For good measure, after people successfully log in, check if their hash begins with `0$`. If it does, rehash the password (since they entered it, you know what it is) with the updated, proper crypt call.

Comment: My 5.4.9 version var_dump gives string(2) "*0"

Comment: crypt('hello', '0$ny0efnQXFkE') gives me *0 as well

Comment: I'm assuming then, that you are using the Suhosin patch?

Comment: The patch doesn't seem to be active.

Comment: @MortimerCat, it's possible that it's dependent on the system crypt lib, but regardless, the `0q` solution looks like the working one. I would just be sure to re-hash the old passwords after login.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way you can recreate the original cipher. Otherwise even a boy scout would be able to break blowfish.

Your best chance is to generate a random password for your users and hash it once again, then force them to change the password as soon as they login.

Comment: I am not trying to crack blowfish, I am only trying to find parameters that would generate the same hash as before.

Answer (score 0):

"$" is not a valid salt value according to crypt(3) so you need to find a crypt implementation that's equally broken as the one PHP/libc used to have :)

If verifying old passwords is enough, use Matthews answer, else try e.g. openssl which currently still seems to accept "0$" as salt:

```
$ echo -n "secret" | openssl passwd -crypt -salt '0$' -stdin
0$z.PXBBy6uY.
```